# Meteor client files prepared for static httpd server

Tags: apache, meteor, client

How can meteor client files be deployed/provisioned to a static http file server ?
Attempting to copy the served files results in a sockjs/info not found error.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is clear. Are you trying to get the files out of bundle or still in a usual meteor project directory in the `client` folder? Is the problem to find the right files to copy? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: found the answer https://github.com/SpaceCapsule/packmeteor, one can load the 'fixed' html page into a browser, showing total separation.

Comment: great! maybe you can post the solution as an answer, so it appears as answered and others can find the solution easily when coming here.